# undefined local variable or method `hej'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello i am totally new to ruby on rails.

I am getting this error:
undefined local variable or method `hej'

in my application.html.erb i have:

```
 <%=hej%>
```

and in application.controller i have this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def index
       hej = "Hej hans" #also tried @hej = "Hej hans"
    end
end
```

__URL/home/index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting hej as a local variable here in your controller so it's not available in the view.  An uncapitalized word - like 'hej' here - in a method will be treated as a local variable when you assign it a value using =.  If you want to make that available to other methods, and in Rails to the views, you need to make it an instance variable by calling it '@hej' not just 'hej'.  To call that instance variable in the view in Rails you need to use its full name '@hej' - the @ sign is important.

Needs to be:

```
def index
  @hej = "Hej hans"
end
```

in view

```
<%= @hej %>
```

Answer (score 2):

*hej* is a local variable. They only exists within it's scope (current block) - and are not available to your *view*.

*@hej* is an instance variable - and is available to all methods within the class. It's also available to your *view*. You also need to call it with @hej in the view.

You need to add an @ to your hej variable (@hej).